# Issue with "File Entity (fieldable files)" module. File Display not working for some users

Tags: 7, nodes, files

I defined a content type called "concurso" which includes an "Image" field in it. The scheme for that field is `Public Files`. In fact, all files in my site are public.

In `admin/structure/file-types/manage/image/display` I set only the "File" field as visible.

In `admin/structure/file-types/manage/image/file-display` I set only the "Download link" option, establishing `[file:field_file_image_alt_text]` as the Download Link in the textbox below.

As a result:

- It works correctly ONLY for Administrator, and users holding the `File entity >> Bypass file access control` permission. They see a link to the image with a text showing the ALT attribute of the image.
- It doesn't work for other users (logged or not) not holding that permission. They always see a link to the image with the file name as the link text, ignoring the text manually set. It doesn't matter if I set a literal instead of the token `[file:field_file_image_alt_text]`, drupal always show the filename of the image.

I'm stucked at this point and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Thank you for your help.

---

Drupal 7.31 - 
File Entity (fieldable files) 7.x-2.0-beta1

Comment: Check that you set the file permissions correctly. Enable 'Image: Download any files' for all users.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. File permissions are right. Actually, all users can view/download the files. The problem is exclusively about the text in the download link.

Digging in the file entity module code, I've realized that the function `theme_file_entity_download_link()` is not called for users not holding the `File entity >> Bypass file access control` permission. I can't figure out why.

Comment: I was wrong, it was a forgot-to-clear-my-cache problem. Your solution worked like a charm, 'Image: Download any files' permission did the trick. Thank you sooo much!!